# “Here it is” or “Here is”

Tags: sentence-construction, pronouns

I am writing a text and I am not sure which option to use:

> a) Here **is** difficult to understand the relations between the inputs
>   and outputs

**or**

> b) Here **it is** difficult to understand the relations
>   between the inputs and outputs

Comment: Please could you add further context? What does the "here" relate to?

Comment: For this project, it is more relevant to focus on another approach of complexity, which is more related to the structure of the system (Osman, 2010a). In this case, IT is difficult to understand the relations between the inputs and outputs or, in other words, the anticipation of the outcomes (Sterman, 1989).

Answer (score 1):

"Here is" would be wrong and incomplete. As a matter of personal style, I would also put a comma after here:

> Here, it is difficult to understand the relations...

Comment: In order to improve this answer, please consider adding an explanation/references for why it is "wrong and incomplete"